# How to load animations made in Blender to ARKit?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit, blender

I made a 3D object in Blender and made some custom animation to it. However, I manage to load the object to the scene, but not the animation.

[This is what it appears to me at the Entities tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJL7C.png)

I was searching about "How to load custom animations in ARKit", but couldn't find anything besides this link: 
https://blog.pusher.com/animating-3d-model-ar-arkit-mixamo/

In there it tells you how to download and play some animations with Mixamo, but I want to load the animations that I made in Blender.

Just for the record, I'm new in this field of ARKit programming and I'm learning by myself.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @ARGeo I baked the 3D object, but when I export it to .dae file and open it again (import the exported file, to see the animation) it doesn't do anything. Do you know what's the problem?

Comment: I answered your next question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55582626/how-to-export-dae-animation-from-blender/55587892#55587892

Answer (score 2):

When we're talking about animation it's better to talk in context of [SceneKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/animation/animating_scenekit_content) and [Core Animation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514) frameworks.

Here's what Apple says about it:

> SceneKit also uses **CAAnimation** objects for animations created using external 3D authoring tools (3dsMax, Maya, Blender) and `saved in scene files`. For example, an artist might create a game character with animations for walking, jumping, and other actions. You incorporate these animations into your game by loading animation objects from the scene file using the **SCNSceneSource** class and attaching them to the **SCNNode** object that represents the game character.

But remember: you need to export your animations as `.dae` file format. And your animations must be baked (you need to transform all animation and deformations into keyframes (for every frame) on the timeline regardless of how the animation is done).

Comment: Thanks for your answer I really appreciate it. I will look forward into that!

Comment: could not find where in the docs says that SceneKit supports animating USDZ files

Comment: Thanks @JuanBoero, you're right. I've corrected the text.