# How to export .dae animation from Blender?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, augmented-reality, blender, arkit

I was practicing animation in Blender so I downloaded a `.dae` file of a car and implemented some animation to it. I wanted to make the car open and close the door and I manage to do that (inserting keyframes to it).

The problem is that when I export it to `.dae`

```
File -> Export -> DAE
```

and import it, to see if the animation was saved:

```
File -> Import -> DAE
```

but it doesn't do anything.

Is there any way I can export and see the animation as `.dae` file?*

P.S. I want it to export it as a `.dae` file because I want to use it on ARKit.

Answer (score 1):

At first you need to ***bake animation curves*** of your 3D model. Use **`Bake Action`** for it:

[image]

> The **`Bake Action`** tool will apply interpolated frames into individual keyframes. This can be useful for adding deviation to a cyclic action like a walk cycle. This can also useful for keyframe animations created from drivers or constraints.

Secondly, use [Collada Exporter/Importer](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/pipeline/collada.html?highlight=export) for exporting and importing `.dae` files.

Watch [Baking Final Animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ZJMoQ3KpLM) YouTube tutorial for details.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you once again for answering my question!